Identify this 1990s Office/ corporation sitcom
Can someone identify this american/canadian sitcom I saw in the late 1990s? 
Here are some scenes I remember:

In the pilot episode a man wakes for work (probably the main lead character) but he was already wearing a corporate suit while sleeping.
In this humorous scene a bunch of people stands and watches a small water leak in a wall, then a main character puts his finger into  the hole to stop the water from leaking, then the people claps and celebrates him.

